# Webdriverio: error after updating google chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

After updating google chrome to the version 62 and when I try my functional tests I got this error:

```
 Uncaught Error: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  at new RuntimeError (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
  at Request._callback (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:313:39)
  at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
  at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I tried to update the chrome driver, but in vain.

There is my dependency:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": " TESTs",
  "main": "config.js",
  "author": "Mohammad TRABELSI",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "2.33",
    "mocha": "3.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.13.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.6.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^11.1.1",
    "webdriverio": "^4.6.2",
    "json": "^9.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4",
    "parsed-url": "0.0.0",
    "q": "^1.4",
    "req": "^0.1",
    "should": "^9.0",
    "window": "^1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "log4js": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

any help  please ?

Comment: Update chromedriver to `2.33`.

Comment: I still have the same problem after updating chrome driver to 2.33

Comment: The key `devDependencies.chromedriver` is 2.32 in your post.

Comment: I will fix this by editing the post

Comment: Have you attempted to update your version of WebdriverIO? - It's now on version 4.9+. Additionally do you have the latest version of Node?

Comment: Also i tried this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

- Download the last version of **chrome driver** - **chromedriver_linux64.zip** - (2.33) and put it in project root.
- Update the **webdriver.io** to the last version 4.9.9.
- Download the last version of **selenium server** **selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar**

This work with Google Chrome 62